# Cron log file isn't updating

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I'd like to be able to add a log file that has a timestamp of the last time the cronjob was run. This is the current code i'm using

```
crontab -l > mycron
echo ""${var1}" "${var2}" "${var3}" "${var4}" "${var5}" tar -czf "$fsrc"/* > ./"$fdest"/"$fname"">> ~/cronlog.log 2>&1 >>mycron
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

The log file is created and the job runs as it should, but the log file has nothing in it. How can I make the log file update?

Thanks

Comment: Take a really close look at that `echo` statement.  Then run it after you run `set -x` and see what it's really doing.  Compare that to what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your echo line.

```
[zbrady@myserver ~]$ cat test1.sh
var1=0
var2=1
var3=2
var4=3
var5=4
fsrc=abc
fdest=def
fname=ghi
>mycron
echo ""${var1}" "${var2}" "${var3}" "${var4}" "${var5}" tar -czf "$fsrc"/* > ./"$fdest"/"$fname"">> ~/cronlog.log 2>&1 >>mycron
cat mycron
[zbrady@myserver ~]$ ./test1.sh
0 1 2 3 4 tar -czf abc/* > ./def/ghi
```

With my slightly modified version.

```
[zbrady@mysever ~]$ cat test2.sh
var1=0
var2=1
var3=2
var4=3
var5=4
fsrc=abc
fdest=def
fname=ghi
>mycron
if ! crontab -l |grep ^HOME=
then echo HOME=$HOME > mycron
fi
crontab -l >> mycron
echo "${var1} ${var2} ${var3} ${var4} ${var5} tar -czf ./$fdest/$fname $fsrc/* >> $HOME/cronlog.log 2>&1" >> mycron
cat mycron

[zbrady@myserver ~]$ ./test2.sh
HOME=/home/myuser
0 1 2 3 4 tar -czf ./def/ghi abc/*  >> /home/myuser/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

Your quoting was a bit weird and was causing that echo statment to mess up. I also replaced `~` with `$HOME`. Make sure you have `HOME=/home/myuser` at the top of your crontab.

One other issue I noticed was that you were trying to redirect tar to the output filename, you should specify the archive name after the -f flag and just >> your tar stdout to your log file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help. It was my echo.